# Performance/Memory differences for Arrays.asList vs. List.of

Tags: java, arrays, performance

We have code that is heavily using `Arrays.asList` and it works perfectly fine. The implementation of the `asList` will provide a view on the array and will simply wrap the existing array.

Now with newer Java versions (as of JDK9) we also have the `List.of` variants to create a `List` based on an array. Depending on the size of the array it will do different things. We mainly use arrays of size 3 and larger. It will create also a view on an array, but it will construct a new array for this and check each individual element for `null`.

Now I was wondering between the performance and memory differences in both approaches. Now before writing my own benchmarks with JMH I was wondering if such benchmarks might already exist or not, or if someone already did some testing.

Comment: I don't know of any such comparisons but looking at the source both approaches seem to be very similar in terms performance. Memory probably depends since `List.of(E ...)` creates a new array so if you keep the original one around you have 2 of them as opposed to the 1 reused by `Arrays.asList(...)`. Aside from that and the checks `List.of(...)` is doing it seems the major difference is more on the immutability side of things so I'd base the decision on that. - Summarizing I'd say I can't see any reason to switch working code to `List.of(...)`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the programmers writing an implementation of Java are free to change their underlying implementation of the `List.of`/`List.copyOf` methods. The performance you see today may change in future versions.